# Forward user via hyperlink to dynamically set records

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, hyperlink

I have a HTML page, that shows all entries. The user should click on the link and follow the link to another HTML, that takes the ID and provides the respective information.

As of now, I am not even able to open the single record HTML at all.

Client-side.js

```
async function filterArticles(e){
    try {
        const queryAddon = new URLSearchParams({
            title:titleDOM.value,
            publishDate:publishDateDOM.value,
            rating:ratingDOM.value,
            topic:topicDOM.value,
            author:authorDOM.value,
            nsfw: nsfwDOM.checked
        })
        let data = await fetch(`${baseURL}/news/filter?${queryAddon}`)
        data = await data.json();
        data = data.map( item =>{
            return `<tr><td>${item.title}</td>
            <td>${item.publishDate}</td>
            <td>${item.rating}</td>
            <td>${item.topic}</td>
            <td>${item.author}</td>
            <td>${item.nsfw}</td>
            <td><a href="/viewRecord.html/${item._id}">LINK</a></td></tr>`
        })
        resultsDOM.innerHTML = data;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Middleware:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(express.static("assets"))
app.use("/news/", articleRouter)
```

Router:

```
router.route("/filter/:id").get(viewRecord)
```

Controller:

```
const viewRecord = async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        res.status(200).json({msg: "success"})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

My goal is to have the user click on a record and the forwarding HTML only shows details of that one records.